# Edit table line as form field using ajax in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I'm working on an admin functionality for an application in Rails.

I've got a table in a page that lists a series of attributes of a particular model "Property".

I want users to be able to click on each line and make the attribute value editable by rendering a partial. In order to do that I assume I need to create a partial for each attribute and have a similar form in each partial with one visible field related to the attribute the user clicked on.

Something like:

**View:**

```
    <tr id="edit_price" data-link="<%= 'edit_field_price_path' %>">
    <% if !@property.price.blank? %>
      <th scope="row">Price</th>
      <td>$<%= @property.price %></td>
      <td>Edit</td>
    <% else %>
    <th scope="row" class="empty">Price</th>
    <td class="empty">Add price</td>
    <% end %>
</tr>
```

**Partial:**

```
<%= form_with model: @property, method: :put do |f| %>
<%= f.number_field :price %>
<%= f.hidden_field ONE_FOR_EACH_VALUE, value: ATTRIBUTE_VALUE %>
...
<% end %>
```

The problem is that I've got over 40 potential fields that can be edited, which means I'd need to create over 40 partials in separate files and add them all to my routes.rb file.

How can I come up with a smarter solution for that?

Is it possible to pass the attribute name as a variable and dynamically edit a single form with jquery?

Does the same need to be done with the routes file?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating all of those partials. They have different types of fields, so I couldn't find any way to optimize that.

Running a single jquery script that identifies where to place each partial depending on the field name to access each `form partial` made implementation a bit easier though. It's been proposed here: [Concatenate jquery variable into Rails partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53490562/concatenate-jquery-variable-into-rails-partial)

Answer (score 0):

for that you can use something like [best in place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) gem, it basically create the functionality you like, not for the complete line, but for specific attributes.

read the documentation for configuration, after doing that, you can create the clickable/editable attribute by doing this on your view

```
<%= best_in_place @user, :name, :as => :input %>
```

this will create the clickable text, and this will fire the input on the frontend to edit it.