# Concatenate jquery variable into Rails partial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, concatenation

How can I concatenate a jquery variable into a rails partial call?

Here's an example:

```
  var myAttribute = x;

  $(this).html('<%= j render partial: "pages/edit_[**myAttribute**]" %>');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you pre assign this variable in the first render?just trying to understand the use case

Comment: No, because it's defined once a user clicks an object. The idea is that the attribute is passed after the object is clicked and the proper partial is then rendered. 

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I see, so this code is in a javascript file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this option, let me know if it works

Use `.load` instead of html:

`$(this).load("/pages/edit_page?attribute=" + myAttribute);`

**PagesController:**

```
def edit_page
 render "pages/edit_#{params[:attribute]}", layout: false
end
```

**routes.rb:**

`get "pages/edit_page", to: "pages#edit_page"`

Answer (score 0):

try with this, so you assign the value to `@param`

```
<% @param = capture do %>
   <%= javascript_tag "document.write(myAttribute);" %>
<% end %>
```

and then do something like this to use it in the call for your partial.

```
$(this).html('<%= j render partial: "pages/edit_#{@param}" %>');
```

Comment: It didn't work. It looks like that doing it that way passes @param the entire javascript tag, which is not something that can be read as a partial being rendered. I guess it can be sorted out by striping some parts out, but I've managed to make it work using kasperite's approach below. 

Thanks a lot anyway.